# Determine whether the function $\alpha:A\times B\rightarrow B\times A$ where $\alpha((a,b))=(b,a)$ is injective and/or surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

This seems so trivial that I don't know if I'm missing something blatent... Is it really this simple?

### Injective:

Let $(a,b),(c,d)\in A\times B$. Assume $\alpha((a,b))=\alpha((c,d))$ Therefore, $(b,a)=(d,c)$. Q.E.D

### Surjective:

I don't even know... I'm tempted to use the inverse, but it hasn't been established that this function has an inverse yet.

Comment: Then establish it does have an inverse. That will give you injectivity and surjectivity in one go.

Comment: You have a typo in your injectivity proof.  You were supposed to show that $(a,b) = (c,d)$.

Comment: @SpamIAm I suppose I missed a step. I intended to say $(b,a)=(d,c)$ as these are the images of $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not quite there yet.

For injectivity, yes, you have $\alpha((a, b)) = \alpha((c,d))$. This is true if and only if $(b, a) = (d, c)$, which is true if and only if $b = d$ and $a = c$ (I assume you've already established this result). Hence, $(a, b) = (c, d)$.

For surjectivity, let $(b_0, a_0) \in B \times A$ be arbitrary. Then, in particular, there exists an element in $A \times B$, namely, $(a_0, b_0) \in A \times B$, such that $\alpha((a_0, b_0)) = (b_0, a_0)$. Hence, $\alpha$ is surjective.

Alternatively, if you have proven that a function is bijective if and only if it has an inverse, notice that

$$\alpha((a, b)) = (b, a)$$

Now define $\beta: B \times A \to A \times B$ by $\beta((b, a)) = (a, b)$. It turns out that $\beta = \alpha^{-1}$, since (notice $\beta \circ \alpha: A \times B \to A \times B$)
$$(\beta \circ \alpha)(a, b) = \beta(\alpha(a, b)) = \beta(b, a) = (a, b)$$
and (notice $\alpha \circ \beta: B \times A \to B \times A$ by definition)
$$(\alpha \circ \beta)(b, a) = \alpha(\beta(b, a)) = \alpha(a, b) = (b, a)\text{.}$$